# Rails nested form: update creates multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-forms

I have menu model and photos model where the menu has has_many relationship with photo. For the image upload, I'm using paperclip. I was able to build a nested_form that creates photo and other attributes in photos table. However, when I update, the record gets duplicated in photos table and the new photo selected in the update form will not be uploaded. Appreciate your help.

menu model

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

photo model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_attached_file :image,
      :styles => { :thumb  => "100x100#", :medium => "300x300#", :large => "600x400>" },
      :url =>  "/assets/menus/photos/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
      :path => "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/menus/photos/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```

form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @menu do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :photos do |photo|
    = render 'photo_fields', f: photo
```

_photo_field.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.input :main_flag, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "true" }
  = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "1"}
```

menus_controller.rb

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])

    if @menu.update(menu_params)
      if params[:image]
        @menu.photos.destroy
        @menu.photos.build(menu_params)
      end
      flash[:success]= 'Menu was successfully updated'
      redirect_to brand_menus_path(@menu.brand_id)
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  private
  def menu_params
    params.require(:menu).permit(:name, :price, :brand_id, :category_id, :description,
      photos_attributes: [:user_id, :image, :main_flag])
  end
```

Comment: the first i've noticed when opened this question - `@menu.photos.destroy`, and I must say this not only will not work, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the code and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very common problem with the `strong_parameters` when using with `nested_params`. ***Whitelisting*** the `:id` in the `photos_attributes` should fix your problem

```
def menu_params
  params.require(:menu).permit(:name, :price, :brand_id, :category_id, :description,
  photos_attributes: [ :id, :user_id, :image, :main_flag])
end
```